# How to open a random link stored in a json file from an image on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a HTML webpage and it has an image on it. When the image is clicked I want it to open a random link which is (currently) stored within a list on a json file on the same server.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><img src="ZEL.png" width="75" height="75"/></a>
```

**nodes.json**

```
[
    {
        "title": "2030",
        "url": "https://zero2030.net",
        "feed": "https://zero2030.net"
    },
    {
        "title": "2040",
        "url": "https://zero2040.net",
        "feed": "https://zero2040.net"
    },
    {
        "title": "2050",
        "url": "https://zero2050.net",
        "feed": "https://zero2050.net"
    }  
]
```

If there is a better `html/javascript/css/json` method happy to take on board

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please include what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way with `map` method for set random `link` from `json`

i have changed `href` attribute to `test` for testing

```js
const links = [
  { title: "2030", url: "https://zero2030.net", feed: "https://zero2030.net" },
  { title: "2040", url: "https://zero2040.net", feed: "https://zero2040.net" },
  { title: "2050", url: "https://zero2050.net", feed: "https://zero2050.net" }
];
const link = document.querySelector("a");
let url = links.map((url) => url.url);
link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let randHref = url[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("test", randHref);
});
```

```css
a:after{
  content :'random href : 'attr(test);
  display: block;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
img{
  border : 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<a test="default href" ><img src="ZEL.png" width="75" height="75"/></a>
```